# Is an equivalence relation (= sign) needed for the real number system or is a consequence of the other axioms?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, real-numbers, axioms, foundations

My math education is based on Calculus or Real Analysis didactical books intended for bachelor's degrees, mainly read in chunks, and never went any further.

Generally, the Real Number System is said to exist and then introduced through axioms, like the ones in the Wikipedia's [Construction of the real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Synthetic_approach). The $=$ sign is always used in all the field axioms and in 1 of the order axioms. Why is an equivalence relation, that is the $=$ sign, never defined for reals? Why is always taken for granted?

My understanding is that for a field, an $=$ sign must be defined separately, while for an ordered field, it may be enough to say that

$$
\forall a, b \left[ a, b \in \Re \Rightarrow \left( a \leq b \wedge b \leq a \Rightarrow a = b \right) \right]
$$

(antisimmetry) that is that this property may define the = sign, in the sense that every $=$ or $\neq$ sign in the field axioms may be replaced by

$$
a=b \Leftrightarrow a \leq b \wedge b \leq a \\
a \neq b \Leftrightarrow \neg (a \leq b \wedge b \leq a)
$$

where the direction $a=b \Rightarrow a \leq b \wedge b \leq a$ is added to the theory exclusively for brevity, but not needed. For example the axiom "existance of multiplicative identity"

$$
 \exists 1 \left[ 1 \in R \wedge 1 \neq 0 \wedge \forall a \right(a \in \Re \Rightarrow a \cdot 1=a \left) \right] \\
$$

may be replaced by

$$
 \exists 1 \left[ 1 \in R \wedge \neg (1 \leq 0 \wedge 0 \leq 1) \wedge \forall a \right(a \in \Re \Rightarrow (a \cdot 1 \leq a \wedge a \leq a \cdot 1) \left) \right] \\
$$

The differences between the Wikipedia's article and the book I'm reviewing now is that transitivity is not included in the book as an axiom (but proved as a theorem), and reflexivity is not mentioned at all in the book. So reflexivity should also be redundant in the axioms listed in the Wikipedia's article and one should be able to prove it from the others (even though right now I'm now managing to do that).

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Usually, *equality* is part of the [underlying logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms).

Comment: See e.g. [Tarski's axiomatization of the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axiomatization_of_the_reals).

Comment: Skimming through the Wikipedia's "First-order logic", there are the paragraphs "First-order logic without equality" and "Defining equality within a theory" which give some hints. So I presume my understanding is correct: in the context of the Real Number System, $=$ can either be included by other axioms (usually taken for granted), or defined in terms of the order relation. I'd really like some other help since things like why $1\ge0$ or $1=1$ puzzle me since I was 14 y.o., started asking desperately and never got an answer. Soon or later I'll study logic deeply.

Comment: But the issue is with the [axiomatization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Synthetic_approach): **if** we want to define $=$ starting from $\le$, how can we express the axioms for $\le$ that use $=$ ?

Comment: Not clear the "puzzle" regarding $1=1$... **IF** we have succeeded in defining $a=b ⇔ a≤b ∧ b≤a$, from reflexivity axiom for *order* we have $1 \le 1$ and thus we have $1 \le 1 \land 1 \le 1$, that allows us to conclude with $1=1$.

Comment: $1=1$ was just an example of things I started questioning as a 14 y.o. boy, like "what equal mean?", and never got answers from the school system, even though asking, and to express my frustration. It wasn't my intention to ask why $1=1$. Now I'm 34 and I'd really like to grasp the sense of this axiomatization. I'll reply on the other things later or tomorrow.